# Are variables not standalone, but just linking?

Tags: java, variables, save

I have written a program little java program, that is just not behaving like what I expected:

```java
import java.util.Arrays;
 
public class test1 {
    static int[] kuerzesterWeg = new int[]{1,2,3};
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] feld = new int[]{1,2,3};
        kw = feld;
        int S1 = feld[0];
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(kw));
        int S2 = feld[1];
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(kw));
        feld[1] = S1;
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(kw));
        feld[0] = S2;
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(kw));
    }
}
```

The output is as follows:

```
[1, 2, 3]
[1, 2, 3]
[1, 1, 3]
[2, 1, 3]
```

Even though I'm not updating the `kw`-variable the `kw`-variable is changing with the `feld`-variable
So my question is: Are "="-characters in java just links to variables or am I getting something completely wrong?
If it is a link, how can this "link" status be avoided?

Comment: This is called a "reference", and that is what `=` operator does on objects, not on primitive types

Comment: How can this be avoided?

Comment: Yes, you have one `int[]` object in memory. It is referenced by two variables: `feld` and `kw`. If you want a copy then you need to copy the array (e.g. `kw = Arrays.copyOf(feld, feld.length)`). That creates a second `int[]` and copies the elements from the original to the copy.

Comment: Ah ok, thank you, you saved my day

Comment: Note that `Arrays.copyOf` is a convenience. You could simply do `kw = new int[feld.length]; for (int i = 0; i < feld.length; i++) { kw[i] = feld[i]; }` to create the copy. Or `kw = new int[feld.length]; System.arraycopy(feld, 0, copy, 0, feld.length);`. Also note that all these approaches only create a _shallow_ copy of the array.

Answer (score 2):

The equal sign `=` is the `Simple assignment operator` in Java, for objects it sets a reference to the object, into the variable, so

```
feld -------> array
kw = feld     ^
kw -----------'
```

To *avoid* that, make a copy, a new object

```
int[] feld = new int[]{1, 2, 3};
int[] kw = Arrays.copyOf(feld, feld.length);
int S1 = feld[0];
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(kw)); // [1, 2, 3]
int S2 = feld[1];
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(kw)); // [1, 2, 3]
feld[1] = S1;
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(kw)); // [1, 2, 3]
feld[0] = S2;
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(kw)); // [1, 2, 3]
```